# Timber/Twig + ACF - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'd like to know if there is any detailed documentation available on how to use filters inside functions.php in a Timber Theme for Wordpress.
INformation seems a bit scattered all over  and alhough the docs on [Github](https://timber.github.io/docs/) are rather helpful I can't find any detailed walkthrough on how to use filters to customize TinyMCE toobars in ACF as detailed on the ACF documentation [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/customize-the-wysiwyg-toolbars/).

Any lead is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use it as usual - Timber do not overwriting standard theme behavior. Just paste code from ACF documentation.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But, it seems to me functions have to be added/registered in a specific way inside functions.php in Timber..? I can frankly not figure that out…

Comment: Custom twig (not WordPress) functions and filters - yes, must be registered via 'timber/twig' filter. You can find example at Timber starter theme https://github.com/timber/starter-theme and Timber documentation. But hooks (WordPress actions and filters) are handled by WordPress itself, no need to register